# Swap drive is listed - but it's not being used

Tags: memory, hard-disk, swap, ram, virtual-memory

I am using a 16gb USB Thumb Stick for a swap drive because I need to do a very memory intensive process. The swap drive says it's listed and installed, but the ODROID is freezing from a lack of memory when it hits 2GB's. Here is the info.

uname -a

```
Linux odroidxu4 4.9.11-odroidxu4 #12 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 23 22:10:22 CET 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

sudo fdisk -l

```
Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1       8192 30493951 30485760 14.5G 83 Linux

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     8064 30719999 30711936 14.7G  b W95 FAT32
```

/etc/fstab

```
UUID=78fe8581-c55e-4665-bbf1-724ea046a7c3 none swap sw,pri=5 0 0
UUID=4d62b70f-fbde-4e55-bf71-089484f36c8f / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid 0 0
/var/swap none swap sw 0 0
```

sudo swap -s

```
master@odroidxu4:~$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda1                               partition   15355964    0   -1
```

blkid

```
/dev/mmcblk1p1: UUID="4d62b70f-fbde-4e55-bf71-089484f36c8f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d528b458-01"
/dev/sda1: UUID="78fe8581-c55e-4665-bbf1-724ea046a7c3" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="cf5e55bf-01"
/dev/mmcblk1: PTUUID="d528b458" PTTYPE="dos"
```

But when the active process runs, swap is clearly not working.
When I use `free -m` you can see that I am completely out of RAM and the swap still says 0.

```
master@odroidxu4:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1950       1913         37          9          0         11
-/+ buffers/cache:       1901         48
Swap:        14996          0      14996
```

Currently the ODROID is freezing and shutting down from a lack of memory.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

mount

```
master@odroidxu4:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=187287,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=399444k,mode=755)
/dev/mmcblk1p1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk1p1 on /var/log.hdd type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
log2ram on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=51200k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=199724k,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=199724k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

trying mkswap right now as well...

Actually that last mkswap turned my swapon -s to

```
master@odroidxu4:~$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda1                               partition   15355964    0   -2
/var/swap                               file        131068  0   -1
```

Comment: Have you done `mkswap /dev/sda1`?

Comment: i did swapoff, then mkswap, then I updated fstab with the new UUID, then swapon .... and it still breaks

Comment: I deleted my comment about the lack of `swap` mount-point after reading https://syshell.net/2015/07/11/odroid-add-swap-space/.

Comment: should I reformat my swap and start over? ... can someone point me to the guide that they would use?

Comment: Your `fdisk -l` output for /dev/sda1 shows `W95 FAT32` for the type.  Should that not be type `82`?

Comment: no idea, how do i change it?

Answer (score 1):

The Odroid C2 has a 32-bit processor, which means it provides a virtual address space of 4 GB. Of this 4 GB, 2 GB is available to user space, the remaining 2 GB is reserved for the kernel (assuming the kernel is configured with CONFIG_VMSPLIT_2G). This means a single process can only grow to 2 GB in size.

With today's growing RAM sizes the 32-bit address space is getting small very fast.

You could try to split the memory intensive process into several smaller processes. Or move the application to a 64-bit computer.

Comment: Its an XU4, an ARM processor.

Comment: Ok, I missed that is was an XU4, and not a C2. But this board also has a 32-bit processor: the Cortex-A15 and Cortex-A7 cores are not 64-bit.

Comment: The C2 does in fact have a 64-bit CPU (Cortex-A53), sorry for the confusion. But the XU4 is definitely 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your swap partition has the wrong type. `fdisk -l` should return `82` for `Id` and `Linux swap / Solaris` for `System`. `mkswap /dev/mmcblk1p1` should create the correct type.

Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq. Another guide would be: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/.

Comment: The Linux kernel does not care what the id is. Besides, the swap is recognized as can be seen from the output of `free -m` in the listing above.